# Deleting part of a huge array stored in file

Tags: file, delete-file

For example I have a huge file, which holds several arrays of data. I want to delete one of this array, which is located in the ceter of the file. Is it any way to do that, without overwriting all second part of the file?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to overwrite all the text in the file.

Since the file is not directly referable via any programming language, the answer to your answer is simply 'no'. One way you could do this is by reading the file into memory and then iterate through the text-file until you find the segment you want to delete. Since you don't tell us what language you are programming in I will put pseudo-code beneath.

```
try {
    // Read file into a String-array
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Cant read file
}
```

By taking this approach you can simple iterate through the text stored in the text-file, like this:

```
while (String.hasNext() //while there is more text in the file) {
    if (String.next().equals(target)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Depending on what the file consists of and how the file is ordered different approches should be taken. If the arrays in the file is ordered by each line, you can simply load every line of text into a separate index of an array. Else wise, you might want to reconsider how you save the text into the file.